# Ruby Selenium Webdriver: Close file dialog on Mac Chrome

Tags: ruby, macos, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, capybara

Here is HTML for me to upload an image for scanning:

```
<div class="capture_group">
  <div class="row wrapper capture_container">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment" id="camera" class="hidden" value="">
</div>
  <div class="wrapper column capture_controls">
    <label for="camera" class="btn">
      <p class="buttonBgText">Capture Passport Front</p>
    </label>
    <label for="camera" class="btn">
      <p class="buttonBgText">Capture Passport Back</p>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The <input> doesn't detect image even I work on it manually so I'm ignoring this element in my test.
Both <label>s trigger file dialog for me to upload file and WLOG I'm using the last one to upload an image. And one **restriction** is that there is no button for me to submit and trigger the scan, even I'm able to upload an image (due to this restriction I couldn't test it with cypress [cypress-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload) which I could only upload but no way to go next).

At the moment the only way I could upload and go to the next page is using [attach_file](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions:attach_file).

```
page.attach_file('/path/to/file.png') do
  page.find(:xpath, "//label[@for='camera'][2]").click
end
```

This is not working for me as I observe it just upload no matter what element I place into the block, and by default scan through the non-working <input>

```
page.find(:xpath, "//label[@for='camera'][2]").click
page.attach_file('/path/to/file.png')
```

This works for me for uploading the image and scan through the second <label>, however the click action triggers the file dialog which I can't close it...

- page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss doesn't work for me as the the file dialog isn't an alert
- I can't do send_key(:escape) in order to close or send_keys(file_path) in order to attach directly as <label> is not interactable
- I also tried setting "select_file_dialogs.allowed" => false into chrome option in env.rb but no luck

I would like to see if there is any script I could close the file dialog after scanning the image successfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file selection dialog is a system dialog so once it's open the browser no longer has control over it, so if you let it open that's pretty much it and you're out of luck.

It's difficult to understand the issue you're having with `attach_file` and why that's not working for you.  The block accepting version of `attach_file` expect you to perform the action that would normally open the file selection box, and then attaches the specified file to the <input type="file"> element that would have been attached to if the file selection box had opened.  As can be seen from your HTML both of your labels are connected to the same file input element (the for attribute for both specify the 'camera' id). This means in order to be able to add both a front and back image of the passport on the same form you would need to have some JS that triggers on the file inputs change event and copies the attached file to some other storage location.  Assuming you have that, and that I'm understanding how your form is supposed to work, then doing something like

```
page.attach_file('/front_passport.jpg') do
  page.find(:label, 'Capture Passport Front').click
end

# An assertion to check that the file attachment has completed
# page.assert_text "Got front of passport" - minitest
# expect(page).to have_text("Got front of passport") - rspec
# Assert for whatever actually changes on the page when the front is added

page.attach_file('/back_passport.jpg') do
  page.find(:label, 'Capture Passport Back').click
end
```

should work. If it doesn't you're going to need to explain in a lot more detail exactly what your page is doing.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, I got _Unable to find visible file field nil with allow_self true (Capybara::ElementNotFound)_ for the block you suggested. However adding page.attach_file(file_path, make_visible: true) I'm able to trigger the scan, but then the application cannot scan the image and would return _Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 433 ()_ (corresponding to: _POST https://services.assureid.net/AssureIDService/Document/null/Image?side=0&light=0&metrics=true 433_)

Comment: I realised from the app flow that the scan has to be scanned through the either \<label> in order to determine the cardtype value and proceed to the consequent APIs

Comment: As I checked manually on the page that clicking the <label>s would give me on the console _[LOG] Action triggered {type: "@@acuant/SET_ID_TYPE", data: 1}_ and _[LOG] Action triggered {type: "@@acuant/SET_ID_TYPE", data: 2}_, respectively

Comment: Anyway I'm able to do it on cypress now. After clearing the concept I just have to trigger the change on clicking the label before doing the cypress-file-upload